# Random Boot Loop

Tags: windows-7, windows, hardware-failure

I am experiencing that my computer is rebooting at random times and not even reaching BIOS. It happens mostly after my computer have been turned off over the night. but sometime just random.

Here's a list of what i have tried to do.

- Tried different RAM
- Used one RAM chip at the time, and switched between them.
- Switched power suply
- Removed CMOS, waited 30min and put it back.
- Changed computer case, so the mobo has been taken out.
- Removed power, pressed on button 30 secs, put power back in, try to boot

changing ram chips helped me for a little while, but the problem came back few days later. if i unplug the power a couple of times it boots up as normal like nothing ever happened.

Hardware:
 - MOBO: MSI Z77-GD55 - CPU: Intel i5 2500k - XFX 7870 ghz edition - RAM:Corsair Value S DDR3 1333mhz 8gb - SSD: Intel SSD 330 series 128gb - HDD: 2x Seagate Baracuda 1tb HDD - Watercooling: Corsair H80i

Anyone that can help me?

UPDATES:

I woke up this morning and nothing worked again, heard this three beeps wich states an memory error, but everything worked perfect after reseating the RAM yesterday.

Comment: Why do you suspect the memory instead of the HDD or drivers?  We need more information on the.  Have you ran `sfc /scannow` to verify there are no system integrity problems?

Comment: Do you get any periods where you can use the computer?

Comment: Yes, i cut power a couple of times, and then i can use it as normal again. i even play games as normal, like nothing ever happened

Comment: @Ramhound i dont know for sure, it might be. I havent tried it

Comment: @Espen - Verify and update your question with the new details.

Comment: What is the hardware? All of it.

Comment: @Psycogeek post has been edited with specs

Comment: Thanks, http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16813130644&SortField=0&SummaryType=0&PageSize=10&SelectedRating=-1&VideoOnlyMark=False&IsFeedbackTab=true#scrollFullInfo even more agrees with anditpainsme assessment. I would rarely say this, I think in this case it might be the motherboard.

Comment: im afraid so too

Answer (score 1):

I will provide the trouble shooting steps I would take to solve this. I've worked the past year or so as level two desktop support technician at a university.

1. Ensure all bios settings are correct after CMOS reset (remove auto overclocks, etc)
2. Run a sfc scan to make sure system files are okay.
3. Try running WhatCrashed to see if it can determine any drivers or faulty hardware that could be causing issues. WhatCrashed analyzes your crash dumps/BSOD logs.
4. Look at Windows event viewer to see if there are any software in particular that are regularly hanging, and then monitor those with software to see what they are interfacing with before they crash
5. Run the relevant hardware tests, memtest (test memory outside windows, if possible), and any other hardware tests -- such as CPU, gfx card, etc. Monitor temperatures.
6. Test the power source to make sure it's not dropping power.

Ideally, back up your data, and remove all of the software variables here that could be contributing this issue, and then see if it's still happening:

1. Format the hard drive and reinstall windows. Install only the base requirements (drivers)
2. Monitor the system to see if the issue returns.
3. If it reoccurs, it is either 1) hardware related or driver related. Refer to the steps provided above to try and determine which it is.

At any case, you must perform the appropriate hardware tests, regardless of what you do:
Stress test the RAM sticks, the CPU and the GFX card (if applicable) and monitor temperatures using stability monitoring software, such as prime95, furmark and memtest.
Also, but sure to check the HDD health.

My gut instinct is the motherboard by the way, since you've replaced the PSU already.

I've had a similar issue with my home PC before. It's also interesting to note that you don't successfully post, which to me signals the motherboard or CPU straight away. I would be interested in finding out the cause of these crashes in the first place, because they'll most likely point to the component that's preventing the PC from posting correctly.

Comment: im gonna try this after work and come back with updates.

Comment: Next time the issue occurs, unplug the PC from the power source, hold the power buttons for 20-30 seconds (you might note the power light turns on, or stays on when you do this, this is normal). After doing this, plug the PC back into the power source and try to boot her up.

Comment: the computer was without power for 5 hours, tried to reboot, same issue. tried to hold in for about 30secs without power, still the same issue...

Comment: So the PC gets power, but never reaches post and just stays on with no display?

Comment: there is power, i can see the screen wake up, all fans are running, but no BIOS..

Comment: Definitely sounds like it is MOBO or CPU considering you've already reseated ram and used bother sticks independently, as well as swapped your PSU over... Does your PC usually beep when it posts? If not, next time it turns on, have a look in your bios settings to see if you can enable the post beep. If we're lucky, we might hear a post error code from the system speaker. At any case, if the issue is happening before that post beep can occur, I could only assume it's without a doubt CPU or mobo... Do you have another CPU + mobo available that you can test with?

Comment: no, i dont have any.. it dont beep, but can put in the sys speaker and test.

Comment: I finally figured out the problem. The RAM slot far right is broken, so the only slots that work are the three ones to the left.
I plugged in the sys speaker and heard the three beeps, and from there i just tested all slots and a couple of combinations. Im glad i dont have to change my mobo yet :)

Comment: Glad to hear it :)

Comment: I woke up this morning and my problem was back.... tried to boot and heard the three beeps.